# Display link to download none PDF file on iframe popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a link to open pdf file in iframe on popup window as script below . In case that a link is not a pdf file, I want to it to display in popup a text "It's not a pdf file, click here to download" but it does not work.

```js
/* intialize popup */
$('.iframe-popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'iframe',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- manific popup cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-+m6t3R87+6LdtYiCzRhC5+E0l4VQ9qIT1H9+t1wmHkMJvvUQNI5MKKb7b08WL4Kgp9K0IBgHDSLCRJk05cFUYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" integrity="sha512-nIm/JGUwrzblLex/meoxJSPdAKQOe2bLhnrZ81g5Jbh519z8GFJIWu87WAhBH+RAyGbM4+U3S2h+kL5JoV6/wA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<a class="iframe-popup" href="https://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.pdf">listofpostalcodes.pd...pdf<p>not supported file</p></a>

<a class="iframe-popup" href="https://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.csv">listofpostalcodes.pd...csv<p>not supported file</p></a>
```

Please kindly help me. Thanks.